# Karate Server feature file cannot access variables in karate-config.js file

Tags: karate

I am working on API testing project and have incorporated Karate to do so. Now my requirement is to create a server which will respond to the endpoint.All this is done but my requirement is to access variables defined in karate-config file in Server feature. I am unable to do so.

For example:
Feature: Sample server

Scenario: pathMatches('\variablevalue) ** methodIs('get')

- def response = default_env

Note: default_env is a variable in karate-config.js file and holds some default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question, we deliberately did not want to mix the `karate-config.js` concept with the Karate server-side.

Normally when you instantiate a mock server via the API you can pass a Java `Map` and all key-values will end up as Karate variables.

But here's a trick, you can do this in the `Background`

```
* call read('classpath:karate-config.js')
```

And this will have the exact same effect you are looking for ! Do let me know if this works, I will make sure this is updated in the documentation.

Note that you can use JSON if all you need is some seed-data:

```
* def cats = read('cats.json')
```