# How to set karate.env programmatically ?.

Tags: karate

I am trying to set  karate.env  through netty server  and respond back what environment is used. Update made to karate.env using java  system.setProperty is not reflecting in feature files.  But java have updated system.setProperty correctly.

Any input will help. Thanks.

```
Background:
* def setEnvVar = Java.type('CMA_Release.Java_Lib.setEnvVar')

Scenario: pathMatches('/orangeFMW/psd2_cma/cctoken') && methodIs('post')
* call setEnvVar.set('karate.env',request.Environment)
* print request.Environment
* print karate.env
# * call read('classpath:karate-config.js')
# few other operations
* def response = "Selected Environment : " + karate.env

Response : Selected Environment : null

Server log
scenario matched: pathMatches('/orangeFMW/psd2_cma/cctoken') && 
methodIs('post')
UAT // Java update the value correctly
not a js function or feature file: 
setEnvVar.set('karate.env',request.Environment) - [type: NULL, value: null]
[print] UAT
[print] 

Java class
public class setEnvVar {

public static void set(String key, String value){
    System.setProperty(key, value);
    System.out.println(System.getProperty(key,value));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT: did not notice you were asking about the server side (netty).

No, you cannot rely on the `karate.env` being passed like this from client to server. What you should do is when you start your test, *BOTH* the client and server should know about the environment. You already know how to do this for the client (`karate-config.js`).

When you start the netty server, you can optionally pass a Java `Map` argument, and all keys and values will be available in the server-side feature file. So all you need to do is pass a key like `karateEnv` in this `Map`.

```
server = FeatureServer.start(file, 0, false, Collections.singletonMap("karateEnv", "blah"));
```

Also see this answer for more ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272220/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter. Will make changes in server side.