# Unable to access config file from mock file after upgrading to 1+ version of Karate

Tags: karate

I'm using the driver.intercept feature of Karate to intercept a browser request and fetch values. In the mock feature similar to the one in [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/mock/mock-01.feature), I'm accessing the karate.config variables following a suggestion in [Karate Server feature file cannot access variables in karate-config.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268824/karate-server-feature-file-cannot-access-variables-in-karate-config-js-file/72299829#72299829)

`* call read('classpath:karate-config.js')`

After upgrading to 1+ version of Karate, this stopped working. Could someone help if you have used anyother workaround as the options I tried didn't work.

Comment: follow this process please. that will not only get you a solution, but it will help the community as well, there is no other way: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas. Unfortunately, my workplace wouldn't allow me to raise an issue in GitHub or let me upload any code and hence I had to resort to adding references to existing examples.

Comment: that's cool. unless we get a way to replicate we don't consider this an issue. you can pass this message on to your leaders at your workplace